# C# is operator with nullable types always false according to ReSharper

Tags: c#, type-conversion, resharper, nullable, resharper-2016

I'm attempting to convert an `object` to a `bool` type and want to convert `bool` and `Nullable<bool>` types. I also want to make sure I make the appropriate casts where possible. So I have the following code:

```cs
if (value is bool)
{
    boolValue = (bool) value;
}
else if (value is bool? && ((bool?)value).HasValue)
{
    boolValue = ((bool?) value).Value;
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Value must be a boolean type");
}
```

ReSharper 2016 informs me that `value is bool?` will always evaluate to false in this stack of if statements. Why is that? That would imply that `Nullable<bool>` doesn't inherit from `object` (impossible) or that `value is bool` will capture a `bool?`.

It's also possible that ReSharper 2016 has a bug; I see that the implementation of `System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter.Convert` is pretty much identical. I doubt that WPF core would have such a mistake in it, leading me to believe it's an issue with ReSharper.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a value type is stored as `object` it is [boxed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).  Boxing of `Nullable<T>` gets [special treatment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx):

> Objects based on nullable types are only boxed if the object is non-null. If HasValue is false, the object reference **is assigned to null instead of boxing** ... Boxing a non-null nullable value type **boxes the value type itself**, not the System.Nullable that wraps the value type.

And, per the [documentation for `is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

> An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is **non-null**, and the provided object **can be cast to the provided type** without causing an exception to be thrown.

So, using both of these you can deduce (see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2w0sXa)) that in the null case:

```
bool? x = null;
object obj = x;   // assigns obj = null
obj is bool?      // false, obj is null
obj is bool       // false, obj is null
```

And in the non-null case:

```
bool? x = true;
object obj =  x;  // obj is boxed bool (true)
obj is bool?      // true, obj unboxes to bool?
obj is bool       // true, obj unboxes to bool
```

So ReSharper is correct: your first branch will evaluate as `true` if `value` is `true` or `false` (whether the object was assigned from a `bool` or `bool?` is not relevant or even known).  The second branch will always be `false` in this case.